# Combine values of different rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this set of data in SQL Server:

| ID | CoinWeightWarning | NoteCountWarning | NoteValueWarning |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 165 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 165 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 165 | NULL | 2000 | NULL |
| 165 | NULL | NULL | 75000 |
| 166 | NULL | NULL | 75000 |
| 166 | 10 | NULL | NULL |
| 166 | NULL | 2000 | NULL |

I need to convert this to a result set like this

| ID | CoinWeightWarning | NoteCountWarning | NoteValueWarning |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 165 | NULL | 2000 | 75000 |
| 166 | 10 | 2000 | 75000 |

INSERT statement:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
              (Id int,
               CoinWeightWarning int, 
               NoteCountWarning int, 
               NoteValueWarning int)

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
(165, NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(165, NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(165, NULL, 2000, NULL)
,(165, NULL, NULL, 75000)
,(166, NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(166, NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(166, 10,   NULL, NULL)
,(166, NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(166, NULL, 2000, NULL)
,(166, NULL, NULL, 75000)
```

There can only be one row per id, filled with the other values (if there are some).

Don't need rows, with only NULL values.

Maybe someone could help me please.

Comment: How are you handling competing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `max` the values assuming we are avoiding the `NULL`s and no competing values on the column..

```
select Id,
    max(CoinWeightWarning),
    max(NoteCountWarning),
    max(NoteValueWarning)
  from test
  group by id
  order by id;
```

See fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/F8FsduHQ